# PHP, PDO Connect statement

Tags: php, pdo

I'm not that awesome with PDO, been learning it to update my PHP standards, I thought I had it cracked,however I keep getting an error.

I have used this before and it works and there is nothing I can see that has changed.

```
        echo "before connect";
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=hostadd;dbname=dbname', $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "past connect";
```

This is my code, the password and server address are correct, as are the variable values that are defined before this statement.

I never make it to the past connect echo though, and I always get this error:

```
before connectError: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Can anyone tell me what daft mistake I am making?

Comment: Are you sure `host=hostadd` is correct?

Comment: This is a network-related problem. Can you reach the DB-server from your machine? Or maybe DNS is not resolving that hostname?

Comment: I've checked it like 7 times, the host address is correct and I can access it through phpmyadmin and my hosting control panel. I can also access the website.

Comment: You can access the website under the host name 'hostadd'? Are you sure?

Comment: 'hostadd' was just something I replaced the host address with as I didn't want to post it on the internet. I have checked the real one against the Host Name section of my database control panel and it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with PDO. To connect an internet service you have to supply a valid and working host name.

Answer (score -1):

if you're already busy updating your coding standards, please either [set the PDO error mode to return warnings](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) or handle the Exceptions accordingly.

Apart from that, the problem is propably that "hostadd" is not a reachable host name in first place. Propably you want to use localhost or another DB server supplied by your hosting provider. If you want to store it in a value, you forgot to concatenate the string. PDO tries to reach "hostadd" which will fail just like when you go into your Terminal and type

```
ping hostadd
```

Comment: There is **nothing** correct in using try-catch blocks to catch Exceptions

Comment: It is however the best thing to do **when debugging**. You get a higher level of detail as compared to a global Exception handler.

Comment: Someone apparently wronged you in this matter. The level is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I removed this passage from the original answer and will research on it, propably I was really wrong. Sorry for any confusion I caused!